# how to pass $(this).data() in ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

i need to pass  $(this).data into success func in ajax. here is my code

```
var product_id = $(this).data("product_id");

var url = "{{ route('client.add_wishlist')}}";

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    product_id: product_id,
    _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
  },
  success: function (data) {
    $(this).addClass("wishlist-comp-saved");
  },
});
```

But `$(this).addClass('wishlist-comp-saved');` is not working inside `success: function(data) {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` will change context when called. When inside of the `success: function (data)`, `$(this)` is not the same as it was inside of whatever is calling this `$.ajax()` request.

For your issue, you simply have to set `$(this)` as a variable before your `$.ajax()` request, and reference it in the `success: function()`:

```
var product_id = $(this).data("product_id");
var url = "{{ route('client.add_wishlist')}}";

var that = $(this);
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    'product_id': product_id
    '_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
  },
  success: function(data) {
    that.addClass('wishlist-comp-saved');
  }
});
```